# Comparing string array with string and posting my result to main.xlm

Tags: android

I am having trouble with understanding how to compare strings in Java for Android.  I have written code to do this in JavaScript and Palm but am new to Java and am a little confused.  Case in point, I am trying to modify the example on the Android Developers site for SpinnerActivity (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html).  In my application I am looking at pipe sizes in the spinner not planets.  When the user picks a pipe size I want to reference an array of pipe sizes and be able to pick other parameters associated with that pipe size like the outside diameter (OD) of the pipe.  I have modified the above sample code and added and array for the pipe sizes and the OD sizes.  I then try to compare what the user picked in the pipe sizes spinner with my pipe sizes array and use the number of the array that matches to pick the associated OD.  There is something wrong with the way I am trying to make this comparision.  I set both of these values as stings but they never seem to find one another.

HelloSpinner1.java section I have changed is:

```
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long row) {

            HelloSpinner1.this.mPos = pos;
            HelloSpinner1.this.mSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            /*
             * Set the value of the text field in the UI
             */
            TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerResult);
            resultText.setText(HelloSpinner1.this.mSelection);

            String[] OD;              // array of pipe ODs
            OD = new String[30];      // allocates memory for 30 floating point numbers
            OD[0] = "0.405";
            OD[1] = "0.540";
            OD[2] = "0.675";
            OD[3] = "0.840";
            OD[4] = "1.050";
            OD[5] = "1.315";
            OD[6] = "1.660";
            OD[7] = "1.9";
            OD[8] = "2.375";
            OD[9] = "2.875";
            OD[10] = "3.5";
            OD[11] = "4";
            OD[12] = "4.5";
            OD[13] = "5.563";
            OD[14] = "6.625"; 
            OD[15] = "8.625";
            OD[16] = "10.750";
            OD[17] = "12.75";
            OD[18] = "14";
            OD[19] = "16";
            OD[20] = "18";
            OD[21] = "20";
            OD[22] = "22";
            OD[23] = "24";
            OD[24] = "26";
            OD[25] = "28";
            OD[26] = "30";
            OD[27] = "32";
            OD[28] = "34";
            OD[29] = "36";


String [] Size;
Size = new String [30];
            Size[0] = "1/8";
            Size[1] = "1/4";
            Size[2] = "3/8";
            Size[3] = "1/2";
            Size[4] = "3/4";
            Size[5] = "1";
            Size[6] = "1-1/4"; 
            Size[7] = "1-1/2";
            Size[8] = "2";
            Size[9] = "2-1/2";
            Size[10] = "3";
            Size[11] = "3-1/2";
            Size[12] = "4";
            Size[13] = "5";
            Size[14] = "6";
            Size[15] = "8";
            Size[16] = "10";
            Size[17] = "12";
            Size[18] = "14";
            Size[19] = "16";
            Size[20] = "18";
            Size[21] = "20";
            Size[22] = "22"; 
            Size[23] = "24";
            Size[24] = "26";
            Size[25] = "28";
            Size[26] = "30";
            Size[27] = "32";
            Size[28] = "34";
            Size[29] = "36"; 



            String ODSize;

            for (int i = 0; i  <= 29; i++){
                    if (Size.equals("HelloSpinner1.this.mSelection")) {
                    ODSize = OD[i];
                    break;
                     }
                }  

        }
```

The associated strings.xml rorm the android site with slight modifications is:

Pipe and Tube
    
        1/8
        1/4
        3/8
        3/4
        1
        1-1/4
        1-1/2
        2
        2-1/2
        3
        3-1/2
        4
        5
        6
        8
        10
        12
        14
        16
        18
        20
        22
        24
        26
        28
        30
        32
        34
        36
    
    Select a Pipe Size

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note, but I see two things here:

1) You have "HelloSpinner1.this.mSelection" in quotes. Inside .equals, that is comparing your variable Size directly to that string ... not the value stored in that object. For example, you're asking: "1/8" ?= "HelloSpinner1.this.mSelection" ... not, "1/8" ?= "1/4" in this case. That might be most of your problem here.

2) You could just use the position of the spinner inside your Listener method. That gives you the position of the selection on the spinner. If you aren't modifying those values, you would already know the index into your array. If you were modifying them, /then/ you could do a string comparison (or concurrently modify your array to keep them up to date).

You might also want to check what you're comparing against once you eliminate the quotes problem. A very simple way to do that would be to declare a String for each value, then run it in the debugger or log the output.

Lastly, as personal preference, I don't like to store long arrays which aren't going to change in the xml file. Just code that up as an array which doesn't have to be interpreted later. That'll give you the array access directly, and speed up execution some.

Comment: I used your option 2) and it worked perfectly.  Don't really understand what you mean by "Just code that up as an array which doesn't have to be interpreted later" but then again I am new at this. Thanks again as your help was very valuable.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're storing your data internally (which is fine). I'm suggesting, though, that if you have an array of values which is not going to change, make it part of the class that needs those values rather than a string array in the xml. IE: in your code: String[] myArr = new String[20]; Set the values once there and you'll have access to them without your code having to interpret your xml string array as numbers. You did this with Outside Diameter (though you should probably define it somewhere else rather than in the method so it doesn't get created a bunch of times).

Comment: On further inspection, you're using the string array for the spinner text, I assume? Even so, you could have an internal array of those sizes as doubles so you can compare your pipe size double to your outside diameter double much more trivially. Either way, just a suggestion as an improvement.

Comment: You have been a great help.  I used the example on the Android site (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html) to create this.  The spinner given there is much more complicated than the tutorial spinner, and thus much of the code in the .java file I am still trying to understand.  In particular I was trying to set beginning value of the spinner using DEFAULT_POSITION defined in this example code.  Unfortunately when I change the value this is initially assigned to nothing happens.  I guess I need to look a litter harder.